# Organizing main page with detailed content

Tags: php, javascript, navigation

I need to develop a structure like the one that appears in the following site:
http://www.autoic2.com

[image]

- Clicking an image, showing the related content
- Clicking in that new content, showing the details

The possibility to have a backoffice would be the ideal.

I'm searching since this morning, but until now, didn't found something usefull to help me with this situation.

Any available script that you know, so i can modify or learn from it?

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This smells of 'not a real question'

Comment: Unless you have an idea of how you want it to work, there is really nothing special about this arrangement. Most product sites work this way.

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for an easy way to administrate the website using a 'back office' then what you want is a CMS 'Content Management System'.

- [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/)
- [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)
- [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)
- [And even more - compare at CMS Matrix](http://www.cmsmatrix.org/)

It's hard to tell if you want 1 page > next page > details page or if you want a popup window on the 2nd page so I'll cover both and assume you mean both. Basically any CMS will have deep pages so if you want 3 or even 100 pages deep then any CMS should be able to handle this. If you want to open a MODAL window then you can use jQuery to achieve this.

Check out [jQuery Modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal), its worth mentioning that the CMS examples I provided will have plugins/modules prebuilt without any additional coding.

Comment: Also look into [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/), it seems to be the go to CMS for product and eCommerce websites, so it might be a good fit for this particular usage.